# Check if the sentence is a sql query and divide the sentence in c#

Tags: c#, sql, string, linq

Consider the following strings in a textbox:

> ([Employee].[Id] =
>   '00000001-0001-0000-0000-000000000000' AND [Employee].[Name] =
>   'Wizard' AND [Employee].[Title] = 'Incident')

and

> ([Employee].[Id] = '00000001-0001-0000-0000-000000000000' AND
>   [Employee].[Group] = 'XYZ' AND ([Entity].[Title] IS NULL OR
>   [Employee].[Title] = 'Wizard') AND [Employee].[Subgroup] IS NULL AND
>   [Employee].[Team] IS NULL)

The above queries are basically a `WHERE` clause in any SQL statement.

I have set of functions in DB stored as string in separate row:

> =, >=, <=, AND, OR, CONTAINS, IS NULL, STARTSWITH & ENDSWITH.

I need to do the following:

1) Check if text box is empty or not

2) Check if text box is enclosed with brackets ( and )

3) Check if query is separated only by function that are available in DB.

4) Check if every attribute must be started with [Employee]. tag.

5) Store the attribute and its value in some list

So far I've done this:

```
    static bool IsRuleValid(string rule)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> keyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            if (rule.Length > 0 && rule.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (rule[0] == '(' && rule[rule.Length - 1] == ')')
                {
                    //remove brackets
                    rule = rule.Remove(0, 1);
                    rule = rule.Remove((rule.Length - 1), 1);

                    //find first =
                    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rule))
                    {
                        int keyIndex = rule.IndexOf("=");
                        string bracketString = rule.Substring(0, keyIndex).Trim();

                        //find left .

                        int bracketIndex = bracketString.IndexOf('.');

                        string leftSubString = bracketString.Substring(0, bracketIndex).Trim();

                        if (leftSubString == "[Employee]")
                        {
                            string rightSubString = bracketString.Substring(bracketIndex + 1, (bracketString.Length - (bracketIndex + 1)));

                            string rightstrBetweenBigBrackets = rightSubString.Substring(rightSubString.IndexOf('[') + 1, rightSubString.IndexOf(']') - 1);

                            //find ''
                            int valueIndexStart = rule.IndexOf("'");
                            int valueIndexEnd = rule.IndexOf("'", rule.IndexOf("'") + 1) - valueIndexStart;

                            //find value between ''
                            string value = rule.Substring(valueIndexStart + 1, valueIndexEnd - 1);


                            keyValue.Add(rightstrBetweenBigBrackets, value);

                            int toremoveIndex = rule.IndexOf("'", rule.IndexOf("'") + 1);

                            rule = rule.Remove(0, toremoveIndex + 1).Trim();

                            if (rule.Length > 0)
                            {
                                int functionIndex = rule.IndexOf(" ");

                                string funcName = rule.Substring(0, functionIndex);

                                rule = rule.Remove(0, functionIndex + 1).Trim();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

First string works well with this, but second one is too complex.

Any help on this?

I will edit the question if required.

Comment: It seems you want some kind of C# SQL Parser

Comment: I would **strongly** advise against treating any input as SQL. Ever. You could, however, treat it as a DSL and run it through your own parser to interpret the intent (and sanity check it), and then build safe parameterized SQL *from that*.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've to do this as it's the client requirement.
Another thought that came in my mind is to read the string from left to right and parse it by finding some pattern in it.

Comment: @vipul_surana nah, don't do that - look into standard expression parsing algorithms; I use a modified "shunting yard" algorithm to do exactly this for some of our internal systems here at Stack - so non-technical users can use a UI or a textbox to write expressions like `slug = 'asksubmit' & usertype=3` etc - it then matches identifiers against the definitions to build an actual query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic parser for your syntax.

Parse your allowed functions into a `List<string>`. I had to replace "IS NULL" with "IS" and have "NULL" be an operand, as the parser isn't written for postfix monadic operators. This allows some additional illegal combinations, but so much isn't checked now I didn't think it would be a huge problem.

```
List<string> functions = new List<string> {
    "=", ">=", "<=", "AND", "OR", "CONTAINS", "IS", "STARTSWITH", "ENDSWITH"
};
```

Use a wrapper function to start the parser:

```
private bool TryParseSQL(string strSQL, out List<string> attribs) {
    attribs = new List<string>();

    return TryParseSQLExpr(ref strSQL, ref attribs);
}
```

The parser has a state variable to decide what it is expecting, either a parenthized expression, attribute or constant, or a function:

```
enum ExprState { Expression, Function };
```

Now we can attempt to parse the expression. This doesn't enforce the '(' around the outside requirement, but you could add that in the wrapper function if desired.

```
private bool TryParseSQLExpr(ref string strSQL, ref List<string> attribs, ExprState state = ExprState.Expression) {
    bool ans = true;

    while (strSQL.Length > 0 && ans) {
        strSQL = strSQL.TrimStart();

        var skipLen = 0;
        switch (state) {
            case ExprState.Expression:
                if (strSQL.StartsWith("(")) { // parenthized subexpression
                    strSQL = strSQL.Substring(1);
                    var tmpans = TryParseSQLExpr(ref strSQL, ref attribs);
                    if (strSQL.StartsWith(")"))
                        skipLen = 1;
                    else
                        ans = false;
                }
                else if (strSQL.StartsWith("[Employee].")) { // attribute reference
                    var attribMatch = Regex.Match(strSQL, @"\[Employee\].\[\w+\]");
                    if (attribMatch.Success) {
                        attribs.Add(attribMatch.Value);
                        skipLen = attribMatch.Value.Length;
                    }
                    else
                        ans = false;
                }
                else if (strSQL.StartsWith("'")) { // constant
                    var endOfConstant = strSQL.IndexOf('\'', 1);
                    if (endOfConstant > 0)
                        skipLen = endOfConstant+1;
                    else
                        ans = false;
                }
                else if (strSQL.StartsWith("NULL")) // NULL
                    skipLen = 4;
                else
                    ans = false;

                state = ExprState.Function;
                break;

            case ExprState.Function:
                var strSqlCopy = strSQL;
                var fn = functions.Where(f => strSqlCopy.StartsWith(f)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (fn != null) {
                    skipLen = fn.Length;
                    state = ExprState.Expression;
                }
                else
                    ans = false;
                break;
        }
        strSQL = strSQL.Substring(skipLen);
    }

    return ans;
}
```

You would call the parser by passing in the variable to hold the attributes:

```
List<string> attribs;

var valid = TryParseSQL(s1, out attribs);
```

Using your examples, I get the first is valid, and the second is not valid. ([Entity].[Title] isn't legal).